# CurrentPosition and current Index are out of sync when navigating items in System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I found out that the CurrentPosition property and the IndexOf method in the ListCollectionView are out of sync when the NewItemPlaceholderPosition property = AtEnd;

When navigating to NewItemPlaceholder, the CurrentPosition property does not change although MoveCurrentTo returns true.

Here is test code:

```
public class Customer
{
  public string CustomerID { get; set; }
  public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

private void ButtonTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

  List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();

  list.Add(new Customer() { CustomerID = "ALFKI", CompanyName = "Alfreds Futterkiste" });
  list.Add(new Customer() { CustomerID = "ANATR", CompanyName = "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados" });

  ListCollectionView collView = new ListCollectionView(list);
  collView.NewItemPlaceholderPosition = System.ComponentModel.NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtEnd;

  Debug.WriteLine($" collView.Count = {collView.Count}");

  foreach (var item in collView)
  {
    bool moved = collView.MoveCurrentTo(item);
    int index = collView.IndexOf(item);
    Debug.WriteLine($" moved = {moved}; CurrentPosition = {collView.CurrentPosition}; collView.IndexOf(item) = {index}");
  }
}
```

Result is:

```
 collView.Count = 3
 moved = True; CurrentPosition = 0; collView.IndexOf(item) = 0
 moved = True; CurrentPosition = 1; collView.IndexOf(item) = 1
 moved = True; CurrentPosition = 1; collView.IndexOf(item) = 2
```

Last line - CurrentPosition = 1 but collView.IndexOf(item) = 2?

Can't figure out if this is a bug in the ListCollectionView or a feature.

Answer (score 2):

But your collection only contains two items. The third is just a placeholder,  which is not a real item and does not participate in collection view navigation.

If you would've consulted the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview.newitemplaceholder?view=net-5.0#remarks), you would learn that:

> "Methods that perform relative navigation, such as the MoveCurrentToNext, skip the NewItemPlaceholder."

and

> "Methods that perform absolute navigation, such as MoveCurrentToPosition, do nothing if the NewItemPlaceholder would be the CurrentItem."

The last quote applies to your situation: since navigating to the next/last item would set the `NewItemPlaceholder` as `CurrentItem`, the operation `MoveCurrentTo` does nothing. It returns `true` as the operation has not failed by definition.

---

---

---

To make that selecting rows in the DataGrid will move the record pointer of the `CollectionView` to the `SelectedItem` you have to explicitly enable this behavior by setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to true:

```
<DataGrid IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

---

To detect if the currently selected item is the `CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder` you can handle the `DataGrid.SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.AddedItems.Contains(CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder))
  {
    // Clear TextBox e.g. by setting SelectedItem to null
    (sender as Selector).SelectedItem = null;
  }
}
```

The `DataGrid` uses the same logic internally to handle the blank line.

---

You can use this class to replace the default `DataGrid`. It exposes a `CurrentActiveRow` property. Everything else works as usual. If you want to edit the place holder row using an external `TextBox`, simply bind to the `CurrentActiveRowProperty` (which also reflects the `SelectedItem` property):

**Usage Example**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid, Path=CurrentActiveRow.CustomerID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<TextBoxEditDataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

**TextBoxEditDataGrid.cs**

```
public class TextBoxEditDataGrid : DataGrid
{
  public object CurrentActiveRow
  {
    get { return (object)GetValue(CurrentActiveRowProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CurrentActiveRowProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentActiveRowProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "CurrentActiveRow", 
    typeof(object), 
    typeof(TextBoxEditDataGrid), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnSelectionChanged(e);

    if (e.AddedItems.Contains(CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder) 
      && this.HasItems 
      && this.SelectedItems.Count == 1) // Only execute on single item select
    {
      var editableView = this.Items as IEditableCollectionView;
      object newEditItem = editableView.AddNew();
      editableView.CancelNew(); // Don't add here. Only use instance and add it on edit started

      if (!TryLazyAddNewEditItem(newEditItem))
      {
        AddNewEditItem(newEditItem);
      }

      this.CurrentActiveRow = newEditItem;
    }
    else if (!ReferenceEquals(this.SelectedItem, this.CurrentActiveRow))
    {
      this.CurrentActiveRow = this.SelectedItem;
    }
  }

  private bool TryLazyAddNewEditItem(object newEditItem)
  {
    if (newEditItem is not INotifyPropertyChanged propertyChangedSource)
    {
      return false;
    }

    PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(propertyChangedSource, AddNewEditItem_OnPropertyChanged, string.Empty);
    return true;
  }

  private void AddNewEditItem(object newEditItem)
  {
    InsertEditItem(newEditItem);
    this.SelectedItem = newEditItem;
  }

  private void InsertEditItem(object newEditItem)
  {      
    if (CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ItemsSource) is ListCollectionView listView)
    {
      int insertIndex = listView.NewItemPlaceholderPosition == NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning 
        ? 0 
        : listView.Count - 1;
      (listView.SourceCollection as IList).Insert(insertIndex, newEditItem);
    }
    else
    {
      var editableView = this.Items as IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem;
      editableView.AddNewItem(newEditItem);
      editableView.CommitNew();
    }
  }

  private void AddNewEditItem_OnPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    PropertyChangedEventManager.RemoveHandler(sender as INotifyPropertyChanged, AddNewEditItem_OnPropertyChanged, string.Empty);
    AddNewEditItem(sender);
  }
}
```

Comment: But such behavior does not allow to connect DataGrid and TextBox to the same ListCollectionView.
When a user in DataGrid goes to a new record, ListCollectionView itself does not go to that record and the values in TextBox are displayed from the previous record.
So the user doesn’t know what record they’re on.
See screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p7l9.png

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Binding to the CollectionView will work. If you create a new record in the DataGrid it will be reflected in all other binding targets. To enable that selecting an item in the DataGrid will navigate the actual CollectionView.CurrentItem to the ItemsControl.SelectedItem you must explicitly enable synchronization by setting [`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem?view=net-5.0) on the DataGrid (or any other Selector) to true.

Comment: I think you want to show the NewItemPlaceHolder in the TextBox? Since the NewItemPlaceHolder can never be the CurrentItem this is not possible directly. The TextBox shows the CurrentItem and the NewItemPlaceHolder can't be the CurrentItem. That's why the TextBox will display the "previous" record as this record is still the CurrentItem.

Comment: The NewItemPlaceHolder is simply a plain `object`. DataGrid has its internal logic where it checks if the NewItemPlaceHolder is selected. The blank row only is not directly edited but replaced with an actual instance of the data model. But you can mimic the DataGrid logic by checking if the selected items collection contains the place holder item. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for DataGrid_SelectionChanged solution. I have many Windows where DataGrid and EditBoxs are connected to the same CollectionViewSource.
I cannot finish my part of the project now because of the fact that there is a dissynchronization in DataGrid and EditBoxs.

Are you sure that a crutch with DataGrid_SelectionChanged is the only way around this problem?
Maybe I just need to configure Binding more properly.
This dissynchronization seems illogical.

Comment: I find it straight forward. The NewItemPlaceHolder is just an abstraction. It has nothing to do with the actual collection and its items. It's used in contex with NewItemPlaceHolderPosition to add logic like DataGrid does. You are never interested in the NewItemPlaceHolder. It's simply a static property of type `object`. You can't edit this item (it's not of the type that the data models are - it's an `object`.

Comment: DataGrid has internal logic where it replaces the placeholder with an actual intermediate model to allow editing. Once the editing is completed. The DataGrid adds this new item to the collection - it is set as the SelectedItem and your TextBox will pick it up. This mean editing the TextBox will not edit the blank line (which is not a real data model). That's why you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: You can make it reusable by either implementing an attached behavior or by extending DataGrid and override the virtual OnSelectionChanged method to set SelectedI6tem to null. If you show me how you have connected the TextBox to the DataGrid and how you set things up I can help you to find a good solution.

Comment: The only problem here is your misconception of what is happening under the hoods with the NewItemPlaceHolder. But to realize what you want to do is very simple.

Comment: I have updated the post. I have added a class that extends DataGrid to add the feature to edit the new row using a TextBox or whatever. Simply bind to the CurrentActiveRow property instead to SelectedItem. Please read the instructions in the Usage section.

Comment: Thanks for TextBoxEditDataGrid but it doesn't work in my cases. You use Binding `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` but I use connect to an external source like this `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource customersViewSource2}}"` . And checking `this.ItemsSource is not ICollectionView` prevents the code in the `OnSelectionChanged` method from executing. Why do you check `not ICollectionView`?

Comment: Even if I remove the `this.ItemsSource is not ICollectionView` check, the following code `TryGetElementType (out Type elementType)` returns an empty elementType.

Comment: I understand the direction of your thought. In the `OnSelectionChanged` method, add a new entry when navigating to `NewItemPlaceholder`. I am experimenting with calling the privet method of `DataGrid.AddNewItem`.  `if (e.AddedItems.Contains(CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder) then typeof(DataGrid).GetMethod("AddNewItem", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(this, new object[] { });`
 But it doesn't work yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236283/discussion-between-bioniccode-and-dmitryb).

Comment: Final much simplified version. Modify to meet your requirements. It will work with any items source.